# how can i reflect changes from AEM author server to publish server?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am new to AEM. and I have two instances of author and publish.
how can I reflect my changes from author to publish.
I have tried from frontend but it didnt work for me..

-Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is. But to view your changes you need to publish your pages or workflow in the author instance, once it is published open your publish instance. Now in browser edit the URL of the publish instance to your website and the page you want to visit. That should work for you!
You can refer the documentation here: [Publishing Pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/publishing-pages.html)

Comment: hey piyush thank you for response.. My problem is that i have two instances author and publish and i have created one site and i have published it but when i am trying to see it in publish instance i get only white blank screen.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the correct path of the resource and that your site is published? Try publishing just a single page.

Answer (score 0):

you will only be able to see the changes reflected after creating a package of your project you wish to see on publish instance. I will guide you through the steps that should be followed while publishing your pages and sites from author to publish instance.

1.Create a replication agent on author by filling all of the required fields like mentioned below:
[image: settings]

[image]
you have to provide your Publish instance uri

use it [enter link description here](http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/agents.author/new-replicationagent.html)

2.Then you have to test connection after starting publish instance

3.Then create a package of your project and install it on publish instance.

4.Now when you'll open your publish instance you'll be able to see default we retail website mapped on your publish instance. You can map your website url in following manner. 
open your publish instance and visit [enter link description here](http://localhost:4503/system/console/configMgr)
Search Day cq root mapping and provide your web page url you want to map for example:
[image]
5.And then when you'll run your publish instance youll be able to see your site like this: 
[image]